# Is this suggested edit that adds an image of Joe Hisaishi to a post that mentions Joe Hisaishi a good edit?

Tags: discussion

Here's the (approved) suggested edit I'm referring to. https://anime.stackexchange.com/revisions/49085/2

While I personally and subjectively think it's a very pretty picture that got added, and I like it, I can't see how this objectively makes the post better. The image is not necessary. There's already a link to Joe Hisaishi's wikipedia page in the post. This image is large and takes up significant space in the post.

The only other change in the edit was to change a word from "that" to "because", and while I think that *is* an improvement, "that" worked just fine.

I don't see what justifies adding the image, and what justifies minorly changing a single word- it seems like it was only changed to cater to the editor's preference.

If I ask myself- "*does this kind of edit make the library of content here better?*" my personal judgement is no. As I said, the image was not necessary for the reader (due to the already existing wikipedia link). Do we want this kind of edit to set a precedent that such edits are okay?

Answer (score 1):

I personally feel ambivalent about that edit. The edit might be "meh", but it is still kind of related to the content (in this case, the image depicts Joe Hisashi with characters from Studio Ghibli's works).

On one hand, I might reject it because adding such an image may be superfluous. On the other hand, the image might add value, even if it is only a little.

I personally skipped the review and just let the community (or in this case, the OP themselves) decide.